# Get GDB to print stack trace on returning to its prompt

Tags: debugging, gdb

How can I get GDB to print a stacktrace (e.g. to run the bt command *automatically*) each time it returns control to me at its prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the "define" command to define new commands that do the normal action and run backtrace afterwards, or you can use the "define hookpost-command"-form to extend an existing command with additional actions.

```
(gdb) define hookpost-next
Type commands for definition of "hookpost-next".
End with a line saying just "end".
>backtrace
>end
(gdb) next
19          for (int k = 0; k<loops; ++k){
#0  main () at optimize.cpp:19
```

You can put this into a .gdbinit file to be automatically loaded by gdb when it starts:

```
define hookpost-next
backtrace
end
```

You can do that for each of the commands you want to extend with backtrace.